# Cannot cross-compile rust/bevy from WSL2 ubuntu via Dockerfile with target stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu

Tags: docker, rust, cross-compiling, libc, bevy

Im not very familliar with Docker OR with rust cross compilation maybe somebody can point out what I'm doing wrong here.
The environment is not relevant but im on WSL2: ubuntu and I'm trying to compile to windows.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM rust:latest

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y
RUN apt install -y g++-mingw-w64-x86-64
RUN apt install -y build-essential
RUN apt install -y librust-alsa-sys-dev
RUN apt install -y g++ pkg-config libx11-dev libasound2-dev libudev-dev
RUN apt install -y libwayland-dev libxkbcommon-dev
RUN rustup target add x86_64-pc-windows-gnu

RUN rustup toolchain install stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu

WORKDIR /app
ENV PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1/
ENV PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/

CMD ["cargo", "build", "--target", "x86_64-pc-windows-gnu"]
```

(I am sure I'm probably installing more packages than I need here but I'm a noob so yea)

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "bevy_try_1"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[profile.dev]
opt-level = 1

[profile.dev.package."*"]
opt-level = 3

[dependencies]
alsa = "0.7.0"
bevy = "0.10.1"
libc = "0.2"
```

(libc here is unneeded probably but It makes no difference if I add or remove it.)

```
Build fails with: 

   Compiling alsa-sys v0.3.1
error[E0432]: unresolved imports `libc::pid_t`, `libc::pollfd`
 --> /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/alsa-sys-0.3.1/src/lib.rs:3:18
  |
3 | use libc::{FILE, pid_t, timeval, timespec, pollfd};
  |                  ^^^^^                     ^^^^^^ no `pollfd` in the root
  |                  |
  |                  no `pid_t` in the root

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `alsa-sys` (lib) due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

I have tried compiling with just an empty main function to be sure it was just the dependencies exploding. And yes the answer is I get the exact same error with empty main function and no imports.

Commands to build / run :

Build:

```
docker build . -t rust_cross_compile/windows -f Dockerfile.windows
```

Run:

```
docker run --rm -ti -v `pwd`:/app rust_cross_compile/windows
```

Comment: `alsa` is the "Avanced _Linux_ Sound Architecture", so is Linux only.

Comment: @Jmp that does make sense.